# IE takes more time in downloading the resources from API

Tags: .net, rest, internet-explorer

We have a web application with vue front end and the .NET Rest API's as the backend, whenever the API returns HTTPCONTENT as a model(object) the downloading in the IE will be faster compared to the HTTPCONTENT of the API being the dictionary. The same API call in chrome takes milliseconds to load.
Is there any optimization that can be done apart from converting the response to an object/serializing the result and sending it to a front end.

[image: IE Network Trace]

Comment: Try to check under Internet options-> Advanced tab whether 'use HTTP 1.1' and 'use HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections' options is checked. Another thing you can do is to refer to some articles online for optimizing the VUE project and optimizing the .NET Rest API code. I can see you have many errors in the console. Try to resolve it. It may help to improve performance.

Comment: We have used G-Zip option to make the download faster, the API endpoint returns the data real quick but downloading the content has an issue(content received is in bytes and the network wait is for ~70 ms). I am not sure of sending the dictionary as the HTTP content type.

Comment: Did you try to check those options in the IE browser? Does it make any difference in the performance? I suggest you make a test on any other machine to check whether it also has a similar issue. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The HTTP options are checked and we converted the HTTP content type to the generic list, still, it's the same, other machines has the same statics for these API calls. Does more number of async calls add to the content download issue?

Comment: Try to reduce a large number of async calls. Request only necessary data. Try to use a cache that may help to improve the performance.

Comment: Adding multiple API calls within the promise to make the parallel endpoint hit solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding